# Set notation for generalized elements

Tags: category-theory

I am currently reading Steve Awodey's book on category theory. On pg. 101 he uses set notation for generalized elements, namely $\{ a \mid f(a) = g(a) \}$ What does it mean in an arbitrary category?

Comment: It means the pullback of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: The pullback would be $\{ (a, b) : f (a) = g ( b) \}$. This is the equaliser.

Comment: So that's basically a syntax for some limits. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of set notation to describe different types of limits is discussed briefly in [Toposes, Triples and Theories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/12/tr12.pdf) in Section 1.6 and 1.7, where it is referred to as the "objectification" of the limit.